# Как отправить первым сообщение юзеру в (python telethon)

Tags: python, telethon

У меня есть чат. Когда в него приходит новый юзер, я хочу чтобы бот в "личку" первым писал этому юзеру приветствие по его `id`, потому что у многих скрыт телефон и @ник.

Я смог спарсить данные юзера.

```
User(id=1152201678, is_self=False, contact=False, mutual_contact=False, deleted=False, bot=False, bot_chat_history=False, bot_nochats=False, verified=False, restricted=False, min=False, bot_inline_geo=False, support=False, scam=False, apply_min_photo=True, fake=False, access_hash=6354077655336188728, first_name='Alone', last_name=None, username='JustAl_0ne', phone=None, photo=UserProfilePhoto(photo_id=5258220180528542820, dc_id=2, has_video=False, stripped_thumb=b'\x01\x08\x08\x8a;\xa9\x1eu\x01Tc\x8f|QE\x14\xc0'), status=UserStatusRecently(), bot_info_version=None, restriction_reason=[], bot_inline_placeholder=None, lang_code=None)
```

Но как первым отправить юзеру, по его **`id=1152201678`**, приветственное сообщение - я не знаю.
Если есть пример кода, был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: телеграм бот не может писать первым пользователю.

Answer (score 0):

```
import telebot

TOKEN = "ТОКЕН ВАШЕГО БОТА"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def send_message(chat_id, message):
    bot.send_message(chat_id, message)
    return "Сообщение отправлено!"

send_message(1152201678, "Тест")
```

При выполнение данного кода в личку вам отправиться сообщение "Тест" от вашего бота! 1152201678 - это id который вы дали в своём вопросе (его можно просто поменять на другой, для отправки другому человеку)

Comment: Могу доработать код если дадите парсер данных, и скажете как вы хотите чтобы выглядело приветствие. И тогда я смогу реализовать код для перехвата данных юзера и отправки ему приветствия в ЛС

Comment: На сколько я знаю в телеграмме не возможно послать первое сообщкние в ЛС ботом новому юзеру. Вылетит ошибка. Пока новый юзер не напишет боту первым.

Comment: Нет! Я проверял и он рельно отправляет от имени бота сообщение юзеру... Причём первый!

Comment: telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found выдает ошибку если отправить незнакомому человеку из чата. Соответственно ели написать человеку который контактировал с ботом то сообщение приходит. А мне нужно первым отправить сообщение незнакомому человеку по его id

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете telebot, а нужно teleton
создаёте клиента  и отправляете сообщение.
Teleton библиотека для уплавдения вашим аккаунтом, т. е. вы имитирует действие пользователя, а телебот управляет ботом который не может отправлять сообщения узерам с которым у них нет диалога.

Просчитайте документацию teleton и как отправлять сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно даже на aiogram  реализовать это,
Почитайте статьи как на aiogram создать approve
Добавляете бота в канал, делаете канал закрытым - заявки на вступление.
Как только заявка будет подана, бот сможет написать пользователю, что писать, на ваш выбор

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).